# Solaar + Ubuntu how to set volume up/down to forward/backward buttons on logitech mx master 2s

Tags: ubuntu, mouse

I have a logitech mx master 2s that I connected to my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, using solaar. I try to change the key mapping so that the forward/backward buttons are volume up/down. However, the only options in key mappings that come up in solaar is "mouse forward button", "left click", "right click", and "mouse back button".

I was previously using KDE, which allowed me to set a system shortcut to whatever the forward/backward buttons registered to. However, GNOME seems to have only keyboard shortcuts.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?